# How to resolve "Error: long vectors not supported yet: qap_encode.c:36"?

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava, rserve

I am trying to connect java with R using Rserve

Java: 1.8.0_151
R: 3.5.0
OS: Mac 10.13.4 HighSierra

To connect R with Java, I typed the following on RStudio

```
install.packages("Rserve")
library(Rserve)
Rserve(args="--no-save")
```

things went smooth and I was so happy about it.

Then I jumped back to Java (Java Eclipse so to speak) and continued typing. Here is what I've done on Eclipse

```
package rserve;

import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;

public class WordCloud1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws REngineException, 
REXPMismatchException {
    RConnection c = new RConnection();
    String path = "/Users/JinhoShin/Desktop/study/R/r_temp2";
    String file = "seoul_new.txt";
    c.parseAndEval("library(KoNLP)");
    c.parseAndEval("useSejongDic()");
    c.parseAndEval("library(wordcloud)");
    c.parseAndEval("library(RColorBrewer)");
    c.parseAndEval("setwd('" + path + "')");
    c.parseAndEval("data1=readLines('" + file + "')");
    c.parseAndEval("data2 = sapply(data1,extractNoun,USE.NAMES=F)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3 = unlist(data2)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3=gsub('seoul','',data3)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3=gsub('request','',data3)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3=gsub('place','',data3)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3=gsub('transportation','',data3)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3=gsub(' ','',data3)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3=gsub('-','',data3)");
    c.parseAndEval("data3=gsub('OO','',data3)");
    c.parseAndEval("write(unlist(data3),'seoul_2.txt')");
    c.parseAndEval("data4 = read.table('seoul_2.txt')"); ########this is what blows me up
    c.parseAndEval("wordcount=table(data4)");
    c.parseAndEval("palete = brewer.pal(9,'Set3')");
    c.parseAndEval(
            "wordcloud(names(wordcount),freq = wordcount,scale=c(5,1),rot.per=0.25, min.freq = 1," + 
            " random.order=F, random.color = T, colors=palete)");
    c.parseAndEval("savePlot('0517seoul.png', type = 'png')");
    c.parseAndEval("dev.off()");
    c.close();
}
}
```

as you notice from the code

```
 c.parseAndEval("data4 = read.table('seoul_2.txt')"); => at rserve.WordCloud1.main(WordCloud1.java:30)
```

I have no idea why it can't read my text file despite the fact that it could write that file.

This is what Java Eclipse console keeps showing me

```
Exception in thread "main" org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException: eval failed
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.parseAndEval(RConnection.java:499)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.REngine.parseAndEval(REngine.java:108)
    at rserve.WordCloud1.main(WordCloud1.java:30)
Caused by: org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.eval(RConnection.java:261)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.parseAndEval(RConnection.java:497)
    ... 2 more
```

and this is what RStudio keeps showing me

```
Error: long vectors not supported yet: qap_encode.c:36
Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT
```

I tried everything I could do to resolve this issue, but still I am on the same spot.

Comment: FYI: it didn`t cause any problem when i did this solely on Rstudio.and i tried to change encoding things as well

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/s-u/Rserve/issues/79

Comment: for those who have a same issue, try to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50410289/running-r-script-from-java-rconnection-eval-exception/50622263#50622263